# Processing 1000's of rows in a .each loop, how to output a puts message every 100 items?

Tags: ruby

I am processing 1000's of user objects in a .each loop.

I want to output a puts message for feedback to the console.

How can I do this, What is the Ruby modulus operator?

I tried:

```
if u.id % 100
   puts u.id.to_s
end
```

Comment: You have the correct idea, but the only things that are "falsey" in Ruby are `False` and `Nil`. `0` is actually "truthy," which is why you need to explicitly check whether the modulus is equal to zero, as Philip did. Also, your idea would have fed output for 99 out of every 100 items, instead of once every 100 items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try that: :-)

```
if u.id % 100 == 0
   puts u.id.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 5):

This will loop 2000 times, outputting a standard-ish message every 100 loops:

```
1.upto(2000).with_index do |j,i|
  print "line #{i}\r" if (i % 100 == 0)
end
print "\ndone\n"
```

Alternatives to that sort of progress indicator are:

```
print '.' if (i % 100 == 0)
```

or a simple spinner:

```
spinner = %w[ | / - \\ ]
1.upto(n).with_index do |j,i|
  print spinner.rotate![0], "\r" if (i % 100 == 0)
  # some long running task
end
print "\ndone\n"
```

*NOTE* - If your `.id` is coming from an ActiveRecord object created by reading a row in the database, then you could get wildly varying output as you loop if your sort is not based on the `id` column. Also, if your database has been around for a while and you've been deleting rows you might have gaps of `id` numbers. The end result is your "every 100" might be very inaccurate.

I'd recommend not comparing to `id` and instead use a separate variable you increment as you loop, or use `each_with_index` or Enumerable's `with_index` to provide you with a consistently incrementing number you can use for your `% 100 == 0` test.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.each_slice` instead of `.each`:

```
rows.each_slice(100) do |slice|
    slice.each do |row|
        ....
    end
    puts message
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the sequence of objects, and check if the index % 100 equals 99 (or some other value between 0 and 99 inclusive).